# Validation Class for checking all textfields

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

Im working on a large ios project with multiple xibs and several textfields in almost every one of them.
I need to create a validation class which identifies whether a text field holds nil value or not and then sends the result in `BOOL`.

The validation class needs to be working on an immediate child level of `UIKit.h framework`.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this.

```
for(UIView* subView in [self.view subViews])
{
    if([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
    {
        UITextView* textView = (UITextView*) subView;
        if([textView.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            UIAlertView* alert //alloc, initialize with text something like this "Please fill up all text."
            [alert show];
            [alert release];

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Although giving more description to your question would help you to get even more better answer!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mayuur. Will this validate all the text fields in a view??

Comment: Also can we make a class which is superclass of UITextField.h and apply similar logic there? If yes how? The question might be a naive one but I'm very new to this language.

Comment: this would be enough to validate all the UITextFields, to check whether they are empty or not. This would be true for each and every UITextView which would be present on the view of UIViewController, including even those UITextField which are on Subviews of the UIViewController's view.

Comment: no need to make any custom class for UITextView for this reason.

Comment: a slight typing error in above answer:                          for(UIView* subView in [self.view subviews])